# How do I run a Standalone vb.net Class Code in VS

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms 

Class CDay
Inherits Object

    Private mMonth As Integer ' 1-12
    Private mDay As Integer ' 1-31 based on month
    Private mYear As Integer ' any year

    ' constructor confirms proper value for month, then calls
    ' method CheckDay to confirm proper value for day
    Public Sub New(ByVal monthValue As Integer, _
 ByVal dayValue As Integer, ByVal yearValue As Integer)

        ' ensure month value is valid
        If (monthValue > 0 AndAlso monthValue <= 12) Then
            mMonth = monthValue
        Else
            mMonth = 1

            Dim errorMessage As String = _
             "Month invalid. Set to month 1."

            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "", _
         MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If

        mYear = yearValue
        mDay = CheckDay(dayValue) ' validate day

    End Sub ' New

    ' confirm proper day value based on month and year
    Private Function CheckDay(ByVal testDayValue As Integer) _
    As Integer

        Dim daysPerMonth() As Integer = _
      {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}

        If (testDayValue > 0 AndAlso _
      testDayValue <= daysPerMonth(mMonth)) Then

            Return testDayValue
        End If

        ' check for leap year in February
        If (mMonth = 2 AndAlso testDayValue = 29 AndAlso _
      mYear Mod 400 = 0 OrElse mYear Mod 4 = 0 AndAlso _
      mYear Mod 100 <> 0) Then

            Return testDayValue
        Else

            ' inform user of error
            Dim errorMessage As String = _
          "day " & testDayValue & "invalid. Set to day 1. "

            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "", _
          MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            Return 1 ' leave object in consistent state
        End If

    End Function ' CheckDay

    ' create string containing month/day/year format
    Public Function ToStandardString() As String
        Return mMonth & "/" & mDay & "/" & mYear
    End Function ' ToStandardString

End Class
```

I have above **standalone** vb.net code from a book I am studying (I am a beginner in VB.net). ***How do I run this in Visual Studio***?? Should I place this code in a module (however, there is no mention of module in the below source code), or in a windows form? I am confused. Please help.

**Fig. 8.8: CDay.vb
 Encapsulates month, day and year.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a WinForms project. Add a class named `CDay` to your project using the Project menu or by right-clicking the project in the Solution Explorer and selecting Add. Copy that code into the class code file and build your project. Congratulations! You now have a `CDay` class in your project. You can now declare variables and create instances of that type, just as you do for any other type. You could, for instance, handle the `Click` event of a `Button`, create an instance of the `CDay` class and then display it's value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I created a winforms project and added the class Cday, and copy-pasted the above code to the class. when I run the project, a blank form opens, nothing else happens. How exactly to display please ( declare variables, create instances of that type, handle Click event of Button, create an instance of class and then display it's value?) ? I am new to vb, hence am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Of course nothing else happens. Why would you expect anything to happen? You haven't done anything. As I said in my answer, you can now declare variables and create instances of that type like you do other types. Did you do either of those things? You apparently don't know the most basic of fundamentals of programming so this site is not for you yet. We don't teach the basics from scratch here. We help with specific programming problems. If you can't even use a type then you haven't encountered a specific problem. Find a beginner tutorial and work through it first. Crawl you try to walk.